# how to tokenize strings based on a word list

Tags: python, tokenize

I want to convert variable names to business friendly names based on a list of known words in Python 3.6.

My list of known words looks like this i.e. the first element is the known word, second is the friendly name for it:

```
Acct,Account
Account,Account
Num,Number
Number,Number
Payee,Payee
Pymt,Payment
Type,Type
```

And my variables look like this:

```
ACCOUNTNUM
ACCT_NUM
ACCTNUM
PAYEETYPE
PAYEE_TYP
PYMT_DT
```

I want the output for the above variables list to be like this:

```
Account Number
Account Number
Account Number
Payee Type
Payee Typ
Payment Dt
```

How can I do this ? The list of variable names to convert is about 10,000. The list of known words is 400,000. Both are available in files.

Comment: What did you try for this ?

Comment: If your known words included `ACC,Accurate`, `ACCT,Account`, `NUM,Number` and `TNUM,Terrible Number` (contrived example), how would you differentiate for `ACCTNUM`? What if `TNUM` was not a thing? Would the answer be `Account Num` or `Accurate T Number`?

Comment: TY @MadPhysicist, The word list would be sorted and 'looked' up in reverse alphabetical order. Longer or expanded versions of a word tend to be the more qualified ones and would likely be a closer match. The output will be eyeballed manually before use.

Comment: @enem. Totally unrelated to your question, but does your user name have any bearing on the Amharic word for "me too"?

Comment: @enem. As it stands, I would consider your question too broad. Could you show what you have tried so far, and explain exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: I don't have a workable path forward, tokenizing libraries look for whitespaces to tokenize. There simply is nothing to split the words. I thought of regexing in a loop off the wordlist but cant find a clean way to do it. We need to regex, replace, and remove the hit from consideration, move on to rest of the string but also move down the word list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, it isn't. Made me google Amharic though, nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a translation mapping of the known words, then use `re.split` to split the variable names with the known words, replace the matches with the mapped words and consolidate the spaces with another regex substitution:

```
import re
known_words = '''Acct,Account
Account,Account
Num,Number
Number,Number
Payee,Payee
Pymt,Payment
Type,Type'''
variables = '''ACCOUNTNUM
ACCT_NUM
ACCTNUM
PAYEETYPE
PAYEE_TYP
PYMT_DT'''
m = {k.upper(): v for line in known_words.splitlines() for k, v in (line.split(','),)}
print([re.sub(' +', ' ', ' '.join(m.get(t, t).replace('_', '').title() for t in re.split('(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, m)), v, flags=re.IGNORECASE) if t)) for v in variables.splitlines()])
```

This outputs:

```
['Account Number', 'Account Number', 'Account Number', 'Payee Type', 'Payee Typ', 'Payment Dt']
```

Comment: Boom. ty @blhsing